# How to break loop when values in array dont fill it whole?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, hamming-code

I have got an array `counter[7]` and it's always fulfilled with random bits (so 1 and 0 bits/values). Also I have got an other array `error_sum[7]` where I want to move only the wrong values (previously searched by another algorithm) from `counter[7]`.
The problem is, I don't know how to fill `error_sum[7]` using a `for` loop until these wrong values are over.

Example (pseudo code):

counter[7] = {**1,0**,0,1,**1,0,1**};

Let's say the wrong bits are {**1,0**, , ,**1,0,1**}, so only 5 (wrong) bits I want to move to the `error_sum[7]` array, to have them there like this:

error_sum[7] = {**1,0,1,0,1**,NULL,NULL}

so only the wrong bits from `counter[7]` are moved to `error_sum[7]`.

I know how to move just wrong bits, but I don't know how to do it until there are no more wrong bits. I am doing it with one `for` loop with `if` (choosing only wrong bits), so I've got the wrong bits mixed with only zeros or only one-s (bits) don't know why.

```
////sumowanie par, które są błędne////
        int [] error_sum = new int [7];
        System.out.println("\n"); 
for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
        {
            if (error[i]=="błąd")

            {
                System.out.println(counter[i]+" "+error[i]);
                for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
                {
                    error_sum[j]=counter[i];
                    if (_WHAT CODE INSERT HERE TO BREAK THE LOOP WHEN THERE ARE NO MORE WRONG BITS IN COUNTER[7]??_) break;
                }

            }
```

Whole my code:

```
package teleinformatykalab2;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class TeleinformatykaLab2 {

    //Funkcja wypełniająca tablicę ciągiem losowych bitów 0 lub 1 //

    static boolean[] bity;

    public static void Losowanie(int tab[]){

        ////int [] tab = new int[110];

        for (int i = 0; i<110; i++)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            tab[i] = r.nextInt(2);
            if (i%25==0)
            {
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.print(tab[i]+"("+i+")"+", ");

        }
        System.out.println("");

}
    /////////////////


    //Funkcja wyświetla bity, których indeks w tablicy jest wartością kolejnej potęgi liczby dwa//
    public static void zamienBity(int tab[], int tabBit[])
    {
        ////System.out.println("\n"+tab[0]+tab[109]+"\n");
        //int [] power = new int [7];
        bity = new boolean[7];
        for (int i=0; i<110; i++)
        {

            if (isPowerOfTwo(i))
                {
                 int j = 0;
                 bity[j] = isPowerOfTwo(i);
                 j++;
                 System.out.print(tab[i]+"("+i+")"+", ");

                }
            if (i%50==0)
            {
                System.out.println("");
            }

        }

        System.out.println("\n");

    }

    //Sprawdzenie ciągu kodem Hamminga//
    public static void sprawdzHamming(int tab[], int tabBit[])
    {
        // przypisanie do tabBit bitow o indeksie potęgi dwa
        int [] power = new int [7];
        for(int i=0;i<tabBit.length;i++)
        {
            tabBit[i] = tab[(int)Math.pow(2,i)];
            System.out.print(tabBit[i]+", ");
        }
        System.out.println("////\n");

        //sprawdzenie pierwszej pary bitów
        System.out.println("\nPierwsza para");

        int [] skip = {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,36,39,41,43,45,47,49,
                        51,53,55,57,59,61,63,65,67,69,71,73,75,77,79,81,83,85,87,89,91,93,95,97,99,
                        101,103,105,107,109};    
        for (int i : skip)
        {
             System.out.print(tab[i] + "("+i+")"+",");

                if (i%25==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        }
        System.out.println("");

        //sprawdzenie drugiej pary bitów
        System.out.println("\nDruga para");

         int skip2 []= {3,6,7,10,11,14,15,18,19,22,23,26,27,30,31,34,35,38,39,42,43,46,47,
                        50,51,54,55,58,59,62,63,66,67,70,71,74,75,78,79,82,83,86,87,90,91,94,95,98,99,102,103,106,107};
          for (int j : skip2)
          {
          System.out.print(tab[j] + "("+j+")"+",");
          if (j%25==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
          }
        System.out.println();

        //sprawdzenie trzeciej pary bitów
        System.out.println("\nTrzecia para");

         int skip3 []= {5,6,7, 12,13,14,15, 20,21,22,23, 28,29,30,31, 36,37,38,39, 44,45,46,47,
                        52,53,54,55, 60,61,62,63, 68,69,70,71, 76,77,78,79, 84,85,86,87, 92,93,94,95, 100,101,102,103, 108,109};
          for (int k : skip3)
          {
          System.out.print(tab[k] + "("+k+")"+",");
          if (k%18==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
          }
        System.out.println();

         //sprawdzenie czwartej pary bitów
        System.out.println("\nCzwarta para");

         int skip4 []= {9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16, 25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32, 41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,
                       57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64, 73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80, 89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,
                       105,106,107,108,109};
          for (int l : skip4)
          {
          System.out.print(tab[l] + "("+l+")"+",");
          if (l%8==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
          }
        System.out.println();

        //sprawdzenie piątej pary bitów
        System.out.println("\nPiąta para");

        for (int m=17; m<110; m++)
        {
            if ((m>=32 && m<=47) && (m>=64 && m<=79) && (m>=96 && m<=111)) continue;
            System.out.print(tab[m] + "("+m+")"+",");
            if (m%16==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        }
        System.out.println();

        //sprawdzenie szóśtej pary bitów
        System.out.println("\nSzóśta para");

        for (int m=33; m<110; m++)
        {
            if (m>=65 && m<=96)/* && (m>=64 && m<=79) && (m>=96 && m<=111))*/ continue;
            System.out.print(tab[m] + "("+m+")"+",");
            if (m%16==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        }
        System.out.println();

        //sprawdzenie siódmej pary bitów
        System.out.println("\nSiódma para");

        int [] sixtyfour = new int [120];

        for (int m=65; m<110; m++)
        {
            //if (m>=65 && m<=96)/* && (m>=64 && m<=79) && (m>=96 && m<=111))*/ continue;
            System.out.print(tab[m] + "("+m+")"+",");
            if (m%16==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");


    ////Tablica liczników par bitów//
        int [] counter = new int [7];

    ////Tablica wyświetlanych błędów//
        String [] error = new String [7];
  //////////Liczniki bitów jedynkowych////        
        int licznik1=0;
        for (int a=1; a<110;a++)
        {
            if (tab[a]==1)
                licznik1++;
        }
        int l1;
        String spr;
        if (licznik1%2==1) l1=1; else l1=0;
        if (l1==tabBit[0]) error [0] = "ok";//spr="ok";
        else error [0]="błąd";
        counter [0] = l1;

        System.out.println("W grupie 1: "+licznik1+"("+tabBit[0]+")" + " >"+counter[0]+" "+error[0]);



        int licznik2=0;
        for (int b=3; b<108;b++)
        {
            if (tab[b]==1)
                licznik2++;
        }
        int l2;
        if (licznik2%2==1) l2=1; else l2=0;
        if (l2==tabBit[1]) error [1]="ok";
        else error [1]="błąd";
        counter [1] = l2;
        System.out.println("W grupie 2: "+licznik2 +"("+tabBit[1]+")"+" >"+counter [1]+" "+error[1]);


        int licznik3=0;
        for (int c=5; c<109;c++)
        {
            if (tab[c]==1)
                licznik3++;
        }
        int l3;

        if (licznik3%2==1) l3=1; else l3=0;
        if (l3==tabBit[2]) error[2]="ok";
        else error[2]="błąd";
        counter [2] = l3;
        System.out.println("W grupie 3: "+licznik3 +"("+tabBit[2]+")"+ " >"+counter[2]+" "+error[2]);


        int licznik4=0;
        for (int d=9; d<109;d++)
        {
            if (tab[d]==1)
                licznik4++;
        }
        int l4;

        if (licznik4%2==1) l4=1; else l4=0;
        if (l4==tabBit[3]) error[3]="ok";
        else error[3]="błąd";
        counter[3]=l4;
        System.out.println("W grupie 4: "+licznik4 +"("+tabBit[3]+")"+ " >"+counter[3]+" "+error[3]);
        //if (l4==tabBit[3]) System.out.print(" ok");

        int licznik5=0;
        for (int e=17; e<110;e++)
        {
            if (tab[e]==1)
                licznik5++;
        }
        int l5;

        if (licznik5%2==1) l5=1; else l5=0;
        if (l5==tabBit[4]) error[4]="ok";
        else error[4]="błąd";
        counter[4] = l5;
        System.out.println("W grupie 5: "+licznik5 + "("+tabBit[4]+")"+" >"+counter[4]+" "+error[4]);


        int licznik6=0;
        for (int f=33; f<110;f++)
        {
            if (tab[f]==1)
                licznik6++;
        }
        int l6;

        if (licznik6%2==1) l6=1; else l6=0;
        if (l6==tabBit[5]) error[5]="ok";
        else error[5]="błąd";
        counter [5] = l6;
        System.out.println("W grupie 6: "+licznik6+"("+tabBit[5]+")"+" >"+counter[5]+" "+error[5]);


        int licznik7=0;
        for (int g=65;g<110; g++)
        {
            if (tab[g]==1)
                licznik7++;
        }
        int l7;

        if (licznik7%2==1) l7=1; else l7=0;
        if (l7==tabBit[6]) error[6]="ok";
        else error[6]="błąd";
        counter [6] = l7;
        System.out.println("W grupie 7: "+licznik7+"("+tabBit[6]+")"+" >"+counter [6]+" "+error[6]);

        ////sumowanie par, które są błędne////
        int [] error_sum = new int [7];
        System.out.println("\n"); 

        for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
        {
            if (error[i]=="błąd")

            {
                System.out.println(counter[i]+" "+error[i]);
                for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
                {
                    error_sum[j]=counter[i];
                    if (error[i]>) break;
                }

            }
                //System.out.print("//"+power[j]+", ");
                //System.out.println("Bity zacne: " + bity[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(error_sum[i]+", ");
        }



        /*for (int s=0; s<7; s++)
        {
            if (l1==1) break;
        }*/




 /*int arryNum[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3 };
int[] counter = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < arryNum.length; i++) {
    counter[arryNum[i] - 1]++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < counter.length; i++)
    System.out.println((i + 1) + ":" + counter[i]);*/
        /*for (int n=65; n<110; n++)    
        {    
            sixtyfour[n] = tab[n];
            System.out.print(sixtyfour[n]+". ");
            if (n%16==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            for (int a=65; a<110; a++)
            {
                if (a==1)
                {
                    sum=a++;
                }

                    System.out.println(a+sum);
            }
        }*/
        System.out.println();
}


    private static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int x)
    {
        //return (x & (x-1)) ==0;                
        return (x!=0) && ((x&(x-1)) ==0);
    }
    /*public static void powerOfTwo()
    {
        isPowerOfTwo(x);
        System.out.println(x);

    }*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] tab = new int[110];


    // wywołanie metody wypełniającej tablicę ciągiem losowych bitów 0 lub 1
        Losowanie(tab);
        System.out.println("\n Bity potęgi dwa: ");
        int [] tabBit = new int [7];


        zamienBity(tab,tabBit);

        System.out.println("////Bity potęgi 2");
        sprawdzHamming(tab,tabBit);
        //powerOfTwo();

        /*int liczby [] = new int[120];
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int z=1; z<120;z++)
        {
            liczby[z]=z;
            System.out.print(liczby[z]+", ");
            if (z%32==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
        }*/

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know which bit is wrong and which is not?

Comment: If you run my code you will se 7 groups of bits, and there are wrote wrong bits (if exist). Whole row of bits is random (at the beginning of code) and then it is checked if parity is ok or not (wrong bits).
My code is (i hope so) an implementation of this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JAMLuxdHH8o

Comment: I can not watch this tutorial right now, but can get back to you later.

Answer (score 0):

This part of code shows me error_sum[7] array, so only wrong bits:

```
////sumowanie par, które są błędne////
        int [] error_sum = new int [7];
        System.out.println("\n"); 

        for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
        {
            if (error[i]=="błąd")

            {
                System.out.println(counter[i]+" "+error[i]);

                int j=0;
                j++;

                    error_sum[j]=counter[i];

                    System.out.println(error_sum[j]+", ");
            }                
        }
```

So, after this loop error_sum[7] should be filled (and it appears it is) with only wrong bits. However, if i want to output this array outside this loop, then i got 6 zeros, and on 2nd position, the last wrong bit from error_sum[7].

```
for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(error_sum[i]+", '");
        }
```

This do...while loop however, shows me only last wrong bit from error_sum[7] array instead of all (i dont know why?). So do...while loop shows me same wrong (last from array) bit as above for-loop.

```
do
                    {
                        int u=0;
                        u++;
                        System.out.print(error_sum[u]+", ,");
                    }
                    while(error_sum==null);
```

Only in first for-loop when i move origin bits between arrays, i got proper output.

Comment: Applied changes in post.

Comment: I got "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" from your  correcting version of my code, it shows that line `code` error_sum[i] = (Integer)null;`code`in for-loop is wrong.